# Tried to bind parameter number 0. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Tags: mysql, sql-server, pdo

I'm currently using a PDO class that works on MySQL perfectly. But when it comes to MSSQL , I get an error when I try to insert data via the `bindValue()` function.

I'm using this method for data binding:

> `bindValue(":param",$value)`

#### Step 1 - Create an array for the table fields in the query

```
$counter = 0;
        foreach($fields as $cols)
        {
            $fieldBind[$counter] = ":".$cols;
            $new_f =  $new_f ."". $cols;
            $counter ++;
            if($counter!=count($fields))
            {
                $new_f = $new_f.",";
            }
        }


output : (
[0] => :field1
[1] => :field2
[2] => :field3
)
```

#### Step 2 - Create an array for the data of the fields in the query

```
$counter2 = 0;
        foreach($data as $cols)
        {
            $dataBind[$counter2] = $cols;
            $new_d =  $new_d."'".$cols."'";
            $counter2 ++;
            if($counter2!=count($data))
            {
                $new_d = $new_d.",";
            }
        }

output : ( [0] => value1 [1] => value2  [2] => value3 )
```

#### Step 3 - Prepare the query via the `query` function

```
parent::query("INSERT INTO $table($new_f) VALUES($new_d)");
```

#### Step 4 - Bind the Parameters and Values

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
            parent::bind($fieldBind[$i],$dataBind[$i]);
        }
```

The query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3) values(':value1',':value2',':value3')
```

#### Step 5 - Execute the Query

```
try { 
            parent::execute();
            return parent::rowCount();
            }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

This method works perfectly on MySQL, but when I try to execute this on SQL Server, I get this error:

**SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 0. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.**

Comment: Returns this from debugDumpParams function; SQL: [72] INSERT INTO dbo._Bakiye(StrUserID,BakiyeTL) VALUES(:StrUserID,:BakiyeTL) Params: 2 Key: Name: [10] :StrUserID paramno=0 name=[10] ":StrUserID" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [9] :BakiyeTL paramno=1 name=[9] ":BakiyeTL" is_param=1 param_type=2

Comment: nvm guys. That was all about TRANSACTION :@@@ Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the apostrophe ''

from :

```
INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3) values(':value1',':value2',':value3')
```

to the following:

```
INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3) values(:value1,:value2,:value3)
```